# Преобразование JSON массива в строку по определенному формату

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, node-modules

Подается вот такой массив из JSON.

```js
let data = {{ $item("0").$node["Google Sheets"].json }} //Здесь лежит массив 
[Object: {"data":[[79645579679,"Добрый день","%0A"],[79645579725,"Перезвоните пожалуста","%0A"],[79182770737,"Выйдете на связь ","%0A"]]}]
```

Подскажите как его преобразовать в строку вот такого формата:

`79645579679:Добрый день%0A79645579725:Перезвоните пожалуйста%0A79182770737:Выйдете на связь%0A` и т.д., чтобы при любой длине входящих данных генерировалась бы такая строка.

Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const json = [{
  "data": [
    [79645579679,"Добрый день","%0A"],
    [79645579725,"Перезвоните пожалуста","%0A"],
    [79182770737,"Выйдете на связь ","%0A"]
  ]
}];

const str = json[0]['data'].map(arr => {
  // добавляем двоеточие в конце номера
  arr[0] += ':';
  // делаем строку со всех эл-тов массива
  return arr.join('');
// делаем строку с массива строк
}).join('');

console.log(str);

let jsonStr = '[Object: {"data": [[79645579679,"Добрый день","%0A"],[79645579725,"Перезвоните пожалуста","%0A"],[79182770737,"Выйдете на связь ","%0A"]]}]';
// удаляем Object: у json-строки
let jsonObj = jsonStr.replace('Object:', '');
// парсим json-строку в объект
jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
// далее то же самое что и выше.

console.log(jsonObj);
```

Comment: подскажите, а с Object как будет? у меня не отрабатывает в таком виде.

Comment: @IndieDev если массив начинается с `[Object:. ..` значит это не корректный json.. Или не надо это добавлять при создании, или можно убрать если это строка. Обновил ответ